How to update fields in array of structures
I'm trying to write, in PowerShell, a simple array of structures.
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
public struct AppInfo
{
    public string PN;
    public string Description;
    public int CRC;
}
"@

$data = New-Object AppInfo[] 4

But then updating any fields like this:
$data[0].CRC = 42

will still preserve the original values. The only way I found how to really change the value in the array is to create a new AppInfo object and copy it into the appropriate element.
Is there some correct PowerShell syntax that will allow me to modify in place?

I don't think you can modify elements in place.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#struct-initialization-and-default-values you can't update elements you would need to assign a new instance of your struct at element X

The behaviour is fundamentally down to the difference between Reference Types and Value Types.
Assigning a struct (which is a Value Type) to a variable creates a copy of the original struct rather than a reference to the same struct instance.
See this for a similar example:
$x = new-object AppInfo;

# assigns to $y a *copy* of the struct stored in $x
$y = $x

$y.CRC = 42

write-host $y.CRC
# 42

write-host $x.CRC
# 0

The two outputs are 42 and 0 because when $x was assigned to $y it created a copy of the struct currently stored in $x and assigned it to variable $y.
Changes made to fields and properties of the structs stored in either variable are independent of each other because they're different instances.
Similarly, your code
$data[0].CRC = 42

is equivalent to
# assigns to $y a *copy* of the struct stored in $data[0]
$y = $data[0]

$y.CRC = 42

write-host $y.CRC
# 42

write-host $data[0].CRC
# 0

so you can see why $data[0].CRC doesn't change - you're modifying a copy of the struct stored in a temporary instance rather than the one stored in $data[0].
If you want to edit-in-place you basically need to copy the struct out to a variable, modify that and then assign it back into the array:
# assigns to $y a *copy* of the struct stored in $data[0]
$y = $data[0]

$y.CRC = 42

# assigns to $data[0] a *copy* of the struct stored in $y
$data[0] = $y

write-host $y.CRC
# 42

write-host $data[0].CRC
# 42

The assignment $data[0] = $y will again make a copy of $y and assign that to $data[0] so they're still independent instances, but now $data[0] contains a copy with the values you actually wanted (i.e. CRC = 42)

Very nice example with the variable assignments

@SantiagoSquarzon - thanks. it's always nice to get feedback, esp when it's positive :-)

This is clarified in the Structure types (C# reference) documentation, specifically in the Struct initialization and default values we can read the following:

All of a struct's member fields must be definitely assigned when it's created because struct types directly store their data. The default value of a struct has definitely assigned all fields to 0. All fields must be definitely assigned when a constructor is invoked. You initialize fields using the following mechanisms:

You can add field initializers to any field or auto implemented property.
You can initialize any fields, or auto properties, in the body of the constructor.


So to answer your question, in PowerShell if you want to assign a value to your struct you can use the hashtable initialization syntax, for example if you want to have an instance with CRC = 42 at index 0:
$data = [AppInfo[]]::new(4)
$data[0] = [AppInfo]@{ CRC = 42 }

# PN Description CRC
# -- ----------- ---
#                 42
#                  0
#                  0
#                  0

